# windows mobile force dhcp renew

Tags: dhcp, windows-mobile-6.5

We have several Windows Mobile 6.5 device deployed and a few of them will occasionally lose the ability to connect to the Internet. I've been able to reproduce the issue by switching from Wi-Fi to 3G over and over again.

When I do recreate the issue, I get the message "A DHCP Server could not be contacted. Using cached lease information."

I've search the google but I can't find anyway to force a DHCP lease renewal on a Windows Mobile 6.5 device. I've also checked the Connection Manager but I haven't seen anything that looks like it will let me do what I want.

Does any one here know how or can point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See iphlpapi.h: IpReleaseAddress and IpRenewAddress

OpenNetCF has a .net wrapper for this and AFAIK there is also a MS wrapper available.

If you look for a free tool: http://www.cambridgevx.com/vxipconfig.html